# Extract pixel value with libpng

Tags: c++, image, png, pixel, libpng

I have a square (1024x1024) 8-bit grayscale image that I'm trying to use as a "landscape" (it's a torrential height model) and all I'm trying to do is just get something like

```
byte = pngimg.at(x, y)
```

I've been scouring libpng's pages and googling but nothing is showing up. In Java it's as simple as a buffered image. Where is the C++ equivalent for a png?

Comment: I mean the 8-bit grayscale value.

Comment: I've already got the FILE* to open the file but I can't find any libpng documentation about actually extracting image data, but all this does is read the compressed bytes. If at all possible I'd like to be able to inflate the chunk that contains the passed coordinate get the Grey-Byte and then deflate the chunk.

Comment: `In Java it's as simple as a buffered image`  The C++ language knows nothing about image types.  You may want to inquire about third party libraries that basically wrap the libpng library, so that pixel access becomes the job of the library, and not your job.  Many imaging libraries leverage existing low-level libraries such as libpng, libtiff, etc.  and wrap all the functionality up in easy to use functions and classes.

Comment: This example may be of use to you: https://gist.github.com/niw/5963798

Comment: How far did you get? If you are able to load an image, you can use `png_get_rows` to get a list of row pointers, and indexing into the row to get a specific pixel value. See http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-manual.txt for that.

Comment: Essentially that's what I finally found.  I'm new to 3rd party libs, and images so it was a chore figuring this stuff out. But in the end I had

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not support image types in STL, so you have to depend on some external library to read pixels. I used to do it using OpenCV library, and it's function [imread](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html). Recently I created a very simple library in C++11 for loading images in PNG, and it depends only on libPNG (and STL). The code that loads pixel data from PNG is at [github repo](https://github.com/pantadeusz/pnglibcpp/blob/master/pnglib.cpp#L35). It takes binary data from vector and creates buffer with vector of pixels.

One note - if you are using libPNG, you have to remember about releasing libPNG resources with  [png_destroy_read_struct](https://github.com/pantadeusz/pnglibcpp/blob/master/pnglib.cpp#L89)  . I had some problems with memory leaks when I forgot about it.